# regex: creating an exception for r:a.?b.?c

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex expression that will filter any variant of "kitchen" that has between 0 and 1 random characters between any of the letters, but it needs to make an exception for "kitchen"

I already have the following, but I need to it not catch "kitchen"

```
r:k.?i.?t.?c.?h.?e.?n
```

I don't mind doing multiple expressions, but obviously it isn't viable to have an expression for every variant of r:k.?itchen, r:ki.?tchen etc.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a lookahead to make sure the string is not exactly 'kitchen'

```
r:(?!kitchen)k.?i.?t.?c.?h.?e.?n
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/wO6hT0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using non consuming regex to make sure that "kitchen" is not covered by regex.

```
(?=k.?i.?t.?c.?h.?e.?n)(?=^[kitchen])
```