# regular expression ten numbers but not ten zero

Tags: regex

can anybody help

I need reg.expresion for validate string contains only from ten numbers

```
    \d{10}
```

but it can't contain ten zero

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144315/regex-creating-an-exception-for-ra-b-c). A regular expression that should match everything it does, *except* for a specific string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
^(?!0{10})\d{10}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?!0{10})\d{10}$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    0{10}                    '0' (10 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{10}                   digits (0-9) (10 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```